# Modelo, relacionamento com DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, dataannotations

Se tenho uma entidade Clientes

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Se eu crio uma entidade Boleto

```
        public class Boleto
        {
            public int BoletoId { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public int IDC { get; set; }
public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
       }
```

Se eu trocar o `IDC` por `ClienteId`, ele entende que essa é a relação com o Cliente, porém como fazer com `DataAnnotation` para que ali seja a relação com o Cliente?
no caso 1-to-1

OBS: Sei que devo padronizar os nomes, para não virar uma salada de nomes, mas em um local queria utilizar outro nome e ai aconteceu o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta especificar qual a chave do relacionamento seguindo o exemplo abaixo;

```
public class Boleto
{
    public int BoletoId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int IDC { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IDC")]
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: especifico no public virtual cliente cliente? show..entendi..obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Apenas lembrando que você pode indicar o mapeamento na própria `FireingnKey`, desta forma:

```
public class Boleto
{
    public int BoletoId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Cliente")]
    public int IDC { get; set; }

    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

Ou usar [Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx).